# Add admin user to ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, production-environment

I've recently uploaded my websapp to heroku.
When I was developing on Cloud9, I added admin user to ActiveAdmin. 
The problem is that I was using sqlite in a development environment, but now using postgresql in a production environment, and so the admin data I added when using sqlite was deleted and cannot login as an admin.

I would like you to tell me how to add a new admin in a production environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create new user by directly through rails console using,

```
heroku run rails console --app <app name>
AdminUser.create(login: 'default_login', password: 'default_password')
```

I would rather suggest you to write `seed.rb` file containing default database insert to bootstart your application.

Comment: Thank you so much, maxumus. I didn't know that I can get access to rails console with a command "heroku rub rails console...". I really appreciate your help.